# Why isn't my button text not dynamically changing based on my computed method in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Some basic information about what I'm working on.  For sake of me trying to figure this out and not disclosing all information, I will input necessary info to understand the problem.  This is using VUE JS.

I'm trying to update a button's text with a method called text -->  {{ text }}  //

Here's what I'm working with:

```
 someName: [
    {
      someKey: "someValue"
    },
    {
      someKey: "notSomeValue"
    },
```

My text method is inside of the computed properties section and is written as so:

```
  text() {
    return this.someName.filter(u => {
      return u.someKey === "someValue" ? "turn off" : "turn on";
  })
```

It is not posting the strings and is instead showing the objects as the button text.  What am I not understanding?

I have also tried storing the string value inside a data property and displaying that.  Also did not work.  I'd expect the text to be one of the two string values inside of the conditional statement.

Comment: Can you show where the method `text()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your text methods like this,you return a array which should return a string

```
text() {
  const filteredArray = this.someName.filter(u => {
    return u.someKey === "someValue";
  });
  return filteredArray.length > 0 ? "turn off" : "turn on";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for a one line solution.

```
text() {
  return this.someName.find(u => u.someKey === 'someValue') ? 'turn off' : 'turn on';`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with the help of [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method as It will return true if any of the objects of `someName` array contains `someValue` and then based on that we can return the button text.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    someName: [
      {
        someKey: "someValue"
      },
      {
        someKey: "notSomeValue"
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    text() {
      return this.someName.some(obj => obj.someKey === 'someValue') ? "turn off" : "turn on"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button>{{ text }}</button>
</div>
```